# How can I view the total number of downvotes that a user has received?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting

Since the amount of reputation lost from downvoting a question is less than the amount of reputation gained from upvoting a question, it would be possible for a user to have more than one reputation point, while having more downvotes than upvotes.

Does Stack Overflow allow users to view the total number of upvotes and downvotes that they have received? I want to find out the total number of upvotes and downvotes that I've received so that I can determine my total upvote-to-downvote ratio. (I take reputation on Stack Overflow very seriously - if I have more downvotes than upvotes, then I'll consider myself to be a worthless person whose questions and answers are hated by the rest of society. On the other hand, if I have more upvotes than downvotes, it might indicate that I'm not completely worthless).

Comment: You can't see this information about another user. Do you mean "How can I view the total number of downvotes that I have received?"?

Comment: Your rep also can't go below 1 so theoretically you can have a billion down votes before you start getting up votes and have positive rep. (Posting bans notwithstanding)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had cause to go looking this very day and [the hard work has already been done](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6014/ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-received) for you by [randolpho](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/38) on the data explorer.

He also did [a single, named (well, numbered) user version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6006/user-ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-received).

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully someone will write a handy script to do this, and that would be a better answer, but here's a way you can find out in the meantime:

Visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

- Every line that includes `(-2)` is a downvote.
- Every line that includes `(2)` is an undownvote or suggested edit.
- Every line that includes `(5)` is an upvote on a question.
- Every line that includes `(10)` is an upvote on an answer.
- Every line that includes `(15)` is an accepted answer.
- Every line that includes `(-1)` is a downvote you made on someone's *answer*.

Any other number in brackets is probably a bonus.

For more detail, see [help:what is reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Aaron Bertrand helpfully pointed out that `(2)` could be a suggested edit as well as an undownvote. That means to count your downvotes accurately, you'd need to check for matching `(-2)` on the same question number to decide that it's an undownvote.

(Even then it might be that you got a downvote on your answer and an accepted edit on another answer. That's rare, I'm guessing though!)

(You can't find information about downvotes on other users except by visiting each of their questions individually.)

Comment: I too looked that link but didnt understand that voting part so I havent post this in my answer. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Well, couldn't (2) also be things like approved edits? And (1) would represent an answer you down-voted that was later removed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes. Good point. Thanks. (edited) That does make counting a bit harder. hmm. You'd have to make some question number hash and count `(2)` as an undownvote if there was a matching downvote, but as a suggested edit if not.

Comment: +/-2 also might come from an accept/unaccept. You need to check both the first column and the last column to determine a downvote received (3 is downvote, and -2 is downvote received)

Comment: -2 will also be there in reputation tab for removal/migration of approved edit post